# How can I quit Steam on macOS 10.12 without force quitting?

Tags: steam, force-quit

Steam will not exit gracefully on macOS 10.12 Sierra. When selecting exit from the application menu or via secondary click on the app icon in the dock nothing happens. The process has to be terminated forcefully, and it will also stop the OS's poweroff process. On occasion the program will exit properly but I cannot see any pattern to it.

When running the application from the command line and then attempting to exit, at first nothing appears in the output, but after a minute or so the following is logged:

```
KQ: Error Unregistering write event KQ:Operation now in progress
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198003850785 [API loaded no]
```

macOS Sierra 10.12.4, Steam API: v017, Steam package versions: 1490228413

Comment: I also have this issue currently on new MB Pro running Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: Also have this issue on MBP Running Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32).

Comment: I am also having this issue. MBP running Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Yep me too, have to force quit it to close. sierra 10.12.3 (16D32), I don't think the model is relevant to this one... it's not a crash just a refusal to die.

Comment: All my software is upgraded to the latest version, and I'm using Steam from the beta channel. macOS is version 10.12.3. Same issue: can't quit Steam.

Comment: In my case, Steam for some reason shows dual "Quit" items in the menu. One of them does not work and so it seems that Steam hangs (and hotkeys apparently send the quit message to that one). If I go to File->(first) Quit, it works.

Comment: Hi Peeps, I had this same issue, logged and issue with steam support and they told me to enable beta client. Here is a link to how to do that: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7021-EIAH-8669 it is now quitting for me and my double quits are gone. If you don't want to participate in the beta, hold on to your butts; a fix is probably coming soon when they get a stable beta.

Comment: confirming @Goran's solution.

Comment: Confirming @Goran's solution again - 2016 MBP with sierra 10.12.4. The beta also got back the feature to have games listed when right-clicking the Dock icon, which somehow was not there anymore. I wonder if it's some sort of glitch with recent installers - I did not get any problem on an older machine where Steam has been installed for years, even after the sierra upgrade.

Comment: Hi all, the issue is still open with valve. Currently I sometimes get two quit buttons. The top Quit works but the hotkeys reference the last entry so CMD+Q still won't work. Hopefully it gets resolved.

Comment: This question should be re-opened.  It is specific enough to answer and has been answered to the satisfaction of many by Goran.  Goran should have been able to make a proper answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @rck No, his solution isn't working. Steam still preventing macos from shutting down

Comment: Another solution is to go to View -> Big Picture Mode, then Exit Steam. After doing that once, Steam seems to close correctly on my machine (Sierra 10.12.6).

Comment: @Giacomo This question has been reopened, please provide your answer as a real answer since comments are ephemeral

Comment: @MrMobster This question has been reopened, please provide your answer as a real answer since comments are ephemeral

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I lodged a ticket with steam support and they told me to enable beta client.

[Here is a link about how to do just that that](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7021-EIAH-8669)

After signing up for beta it is now quitting for me and my double quits are gone. If you don't want to participate in the beta, hold on to your butts; a fix is probably coming soon when they get a stable beta.

-- I did say soon in my initial comment back on Apr 5 '17 so perhaps not so soon if you are here now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View -> Big Picture Mode, then Exit Steam. After doing that once, Steam seems to close correctly on my machine (Sierra 10.12.6 - dec ‘17).